# Yii2-Smarty: Cannot Access Methods of $this-object

Tags: methods, yii2, smarty3

## Yii2-Smarty: Cannot Access Object Methods

I set up Yii2 with [smarty extension](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-smarty).

Now I am trying to simply convert the `layouts/main.php` file to a smarty template. For that I need access to the current `yii\web\View` object which is given from the extension as [`$this`-smarty-variable](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-smarty/blob/master/docs/guide/template-syntax.md#additional-variables).

I've validated that the smarty `$this` variable was the same as the view-object through `var_dump()`-ing and comparing both.

#### Problem

According to the smarty3 docs I should be able to call a method on the `$this`-object from smarty templates like this: `{var_dump($this->head())}`.

Applying the above script in a template just always returns `NULL` which let me guess that no method call had happen.

#### Question

How can I call a method from an object which is given to smarty from PHP ?

1. Define variable for use in smarty: `$template->assign('app', \Yii::$app);`
2. Call method on variable in smarty template: `{$app->getSession();}`

What am I doing wrong ?

(my current smarty layout: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PWBTmFnZ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Applying the above script in a template just always returns NULL which let me guess that no method call had happen.

the [head()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#head%28%29-detail) method does not return anything so if you see null that is correct.

You can call the method like this:

```
{$this->head()}
```

Comment: This the answer to my actual question. I tried to include the assets in my layout per call to `yii\web\View::head()` method. 

However, this **is not working** (for me) if not all markers (`beginPage, beginBody, head, endBody, endPage`) are set in the layout !